# Breakpoint doesn't get hit when debugging ember addon that runs a node file in Webstorm

Tags: node.js, webstorm, ember-cli

I have a debug config set up like this:

[image]

I have a breakpoint in a file (inside the run function) that this addon runs when `ember deploy is run`

Node file that gets run when ember deploy is run:

```
var RSVP  = require('rsvp');
var Promise = RSVP.Promise;
var exec = require('child_process').exec;

module.exports = {
   run:function(){
      //breakpoint in this code
```

however my breakpoint never gets hit.

Comment: Where do you call `run()`?  Exporting it is not enough, unless I'm missing something.

Comment: Ember CLI calls it, it is part of the config, it does run. It's just that the breakpoint is not hit